# How to return an array with only one of each id?

Tags: sql, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Creating a workout tracker using React and Ruby on Rails. In my db, A routine has many exercises and an exercise has many routines via the exercise_sets join table. Exercise_set belongs to a routine and an exercise. I want to filter this array of exercises to show only one of each instead of five. Sorry for the noobness but what are some ways I could return ["Lat Pulldown", "Plate-Loaded Row", and "Bent-Over Dumbbell Row"]?

I’m currently getting my lists via the RoutineSerializer by declaring has_many :exercise_sets and has_many :exercises

[Image of a routine's exercise_sets and exercises](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7JU8.png)

Comment: Can you post how you are going about getting the current lists?

Comment: @engineersmnky went ahead and updated the post with that info, let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in ReactJs using Javascript:

**Option 1:**

loop through the **excercise_sets** array and save the elements into a new array and validate that the **excercise_id** is not repeated:

```
let result = [];
excercise_sets.forEach(mapItem => {
  if (
    !result.find(resultItem => resultItem.excercise_id === mapItem.excercise_id)
  ) {
    result.push(mapItem);
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

**Option 2:**

Use reducer to create a new accumulative array whit the same logic, checking that the current **excercise_id** don't exist in the accumulated array

```
const result = excercise_sets.reduce(
  (accumulated, currentElement) =>
    accumulated.every(({excercise_id}) => excercise_id != currentElement.excercise_id) //evaluates if no element already has this exercise id
      ? [...accumulated, currentElement] //true - if none have it, add the old elements with the new one
      : accumulated, //false, keep the items you already have
  [excercise_sets[0]]
);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Why make the user's browser do this work, or allow the user to bork it up? This should be done server-side with ruby.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! I tried implementing this but am only getting a set object in the console.

Comment: Ooo I just changed it to where I use the reducer on exercises instead of exercise_sets and that works perfectly! Thank you so muchhhh

Comment: @BenFenner yup just realized I can use the .uniq method in my controller. I thought it could only be used in the model!